# Как сделать проверку существования записи?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, есть before_action:

```
before_action :set_film_session, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Его код

```
def set_film_session
  @film_session = FilmSession.find(params[:id])
end
```

Проблема в том, что если в адресной строке написать например - /film_sessions/0, то появляется ошибка Couldn't find FilmSession with 'id'=0. 
Все что я пишу внутри ешена show или в set_film_session(после строчки присвоения) не срабатывает из за этого не могу сделать проверку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `find()` всегда генерирует исключение, если искомый объект не найден, можно его перехватить, однако это не самая удачная практика. Если вы хотите проверить существование сессии, лучше избегать генерации исключения, воспользовавшись методом `where()` с последующим вызовом `first()`, например

```
def set_film_session
  @film_session = FilmSession.where(id: params[:id]).limit(1).first
  #if @film_session.present?
  #if @film_session.blank?
end
```

После выполнения запроса, вы сможете проверить содержимое переменной `@film_session`.

Comment: `first` сам сделает `LIMIT 1`. А припахивать ActiveSupport'овые `present?` и `blank?` ради проверки на `nil` это чутка перебор что ли :) Есть же `nil?`, который причём нужен лишь для того, чтобы различить `false` и `nil`, когда `false` тут невозможен, т. е. вообще достаточно `if @film_session`.

Answer (score 2):

> Couldn't find FilmSession with 'id'=0

Это исключение `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. Знаете, что делает Rails в `production` с ним?

**Отдаёт стандартный 404.**

Учитывая то, что у вас на сайте не ожидается ссылок на несуществующие записи (правда ведь?), вполне сносный вариант просто **оставить всё как есть**. Если пользователь сам написал ссылку, он вполне готов лицезреть 404 из-за ошибки в URL.

**Если** у вас первичный ключ этой таблицы `id`, то исключения можно избежать finder'ом поля, который в случае отсутствия возвращает `nil`:

```
@film_session = FilmSession.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

Это один из моментов, где Rails **не вполне согласован**: можно было б предполагать, что `find` будет возвращать `nil`, а `find!` взрываться с исключением...
**Но нет,** метода `find!` не существует.

Comment: Спасибо, информативно)