# Ошибка Missing template questions/update в тесте Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Здравствуйте, есть такой код в контроллере:

```
before_action :set_question, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote,:downvote]  

  def show
  end

  def update
    if @question.update(question_params)
      flash[:success] = "Question was successufly updated"
      redirect_to question_path(@question)
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  # DELETE /questions/1
  # DELETE /questions/1.json
  def destroy
    @question.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Question was successfully destroyed."
    redirect_to questions_url
  end

def set_question
  @question = Question.where(id: params[:id]).first
  unless @question
    render status: 404
  end
end
```

И такой тест

```
  def self.it_renders_404_page_when_question_is_not_found(*actions)
    actions.each do |a|
      it "#{a} renders 404 page when questions is not found" do
        verb = if a == :update
          "PATCH"
        elsif a == :destroy
          "DELETE"
        else
          "GET"
        end
        process a, verb, {id: 0}
        expect(response).to have_http_status(404)
      end
    end
  end

it_renders_404_page_when_question_is_not_found :show, :edit, :update, :destroy
```

На методе show все хорошо, а вот на update и destroy такая ошибка:

```
 Failure/Error: render status: 404

 ActionView::MissingTemplate:
   Missing template questions/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
     * "/home/max/Desktop/stack/app/views"
     * "/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.2/app/views"
     * "/home/max/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/devise-3.5.5/app/views"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Тесты вполне справедливо упали.** Приложение в таких условиях тоже упало бы.

Описание ошибки вполне понятно и соответствует неправильности логики:

```
 Failure/Error: render status: 404    # ищем, где такая строчка
   Missing template questions/destroy # замечаем, что этого шаблона и правда нет
```

Где же связь? В поведении `render` по умолчанию. То, что не указано у него в аргументах, будет не пустым, а заполненным тем, что положено по умолчанию. А по умолчанию телом ответа должна быть вьюха `<контроллер>/<экшн>`, что мы и наблюдаем.

[Прошлый мой ответ на эту тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527665/181100) вы, видимо, не восприняли всерьёз. Если вы хотите в Rails отдать "просто 404", вам достаточно создать ситуацию, в которой в нужный момент выстрелит исключение `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`.

Посему, весь ваш `set_question` можно заменить на одну строчку:

```
@question = Question.find(params[:id])
```

...и он **уже** будет корректно реагировать на ситуацию, когда вопрос не найден.

Не городите лишнего кода там, где он просто не нужен.

Comment: Если заменить весь set_question на одну эту строчку, то возникает 4 ошибки - Couldn't find Question with 'id'=0. Если заменить на @question = Question.find_by_id(params[:id]), то выскакивает сначала 4 ошибки -undefined method `authenticate', а после добавления в тест         user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, role: "moder") 
sign_in user появляется ещё 4 ошибки: undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass,  param is missing or the value is empty: question, expected the response to have status code 404 but it was 200, undefined method `visitors' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Если же в set_question снова вернуть       unless question
        render status: 404
      end
и оставить его так:       question = Question.find_by_id(params[:id])
      unless question
        render status: 404
      end, то опять те же ошибки - Missing template

Comment: @MaximCherevatov и что? RecordNotFound, который выдаёт "Couldn't find..." это нормально. Ещё раз посмотрите ответ по ссылке.

Comment: @MaximCherevatov почему missing template получается, я написал. Вы ответ вообще читали?

Comment: конечно прочитал, но понять что делать не выходит. Каждый раз получаются новые ошибки. Если не  RecordNotFound, то Missing template. Они словно заменяют друг друга..

Comment: @MaximCherevatov Прочитали, но, видимо, не поняли. Получить RecordNotFound – **нормально**. Если ожидается, что запись не найдётся, это ровно то, что нужно.

Comment: то есть я должен написать в самом тесте что-то типа такого: expect(response).to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) ?

Comment: @MaximCherevatov это тест контроллера? Тогда да, наверное (хотя в Rails 5 их больше нет). В функциональном можно ожидать ответа с 404.

Comment: Но на сколько я понимаю тест не срабатывает. Как только появляется ошибка - то что ожидается в результате уже не проверяется.

Comment: @MaximCherevatov потому что матчер raise_error ставится на expect с блоком, в котором исключение возникает. Оно возникает не в response, а в process.